# ASP.Net make menu items occupy full width of Horizontal Menu

Tags: html, css, asp.net, menu, menuitem

I have a horizontal menu bar here:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" EnableViewState="false" Width="100%" IncludeStyleBlock="true" StaticMenuItemStyle-BackColor="black" StaticHoverStyle-BackColor="#F26522" StaticSelectedStyle-BackColor="#F26522">
        <Items >
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="B1TSUser.aspx" Text="B1TS User"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Client.aspx" Text="Client"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="UserClient.aspx" Text="User Client"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Project.aspx" Text="Project"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
```

It contains 4 items currently and I'd like those items to automatically occupy the whole horizontal menu bar.  It would be ideal if I could get it to always occupy all the space no matter how many menu items there are but that's not too important.

Here is my relevant css:

```
#NavigationMenu {
        font-family: downlinkregular;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        border-left: 2px solid white;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }
    #NavigationMenu a {
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        color: white;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }
```

Currently the width for the menu items is 200px but that is just to make everything even for now, I'd like the width to be a quarter of the whole menu for each case.  Unfortunately making the width 25% doesn't work like I assumed it would.  Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is `box-sizing:border-box;` what you're looking for? this way you can take padding and borders out of the equation when using percentage widths.

off the top of my head i cant remember how exactly the asp.net menus render, i'm just assuming it's using a list.

[here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y2hw6c5/)

please note that you may need to use vendor prefixes to make this attribute work on some older browsers

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, I'm also not completely sure how asp.net menus render which is why I'm struggling a bit here.  But I need to use them to get my master page selected item working.

Comment: would adding RenderingMode="List" to the menu control help matters, that should prevent it being rendered as a table and be rendered as a list instead.

Comment: That doesn't work either, I think it's default rendering mode is list anyway but I've added that and it still hasn't changed things.